# How can I get the runtime length of a movie in .m4v format with VBScript, command line, or some other way?

Tags: windows, command-line, vbscript

I'm looking to get the runtime length of a movie in .m4v. I am going to loop through a folder of movies and then spit out the runtimes to a MySQL server database.

What is a simplest way to get the runtime length with command line, VBScript, or some other quick scriptable way on a Windows box?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CMD line version of MediaInfo from Sourceforge can give you that IIRC.